# Find Video Duration From Content-Length in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers

Is there any way to calculate the video duration in a millisecond from content-length?

```
request
  .get("http://myvideourl.com/filename.mp4")
  .on("response", response => {
    const content_length = response.headers.content-length;// "content-length": "1986943971"
    res.json({
      stream_duration: "",
      thumb: thumb,
      size: content_length,
    });
  });
```

Note : Video Format is MP4 , *res* is express object, *request* is a httpclient library in NodeJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration)
It will help you to get the video length even from an url

```
const { getVideoDurationInSeconds } = require('get-video-duration');
getVideoDurationInSeconds('http://myvideourl.com/filename.mp4').then((duration) => {
    console.log(duration)
})
```

Of course you can then convert it into milliseconds. (x1000).

Comment: first of all, it does not provides seconds accurately and it takes too much time to respond.

Comment: Oh let me take a look for a better approach

Comment: It is not providing accurate data

Comment: How accurate/inaccurate is this @MalayM?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure regarding 'Content-Length', But [this gist will give you the video duration](https://gist.github.com/Elements-/cf063254730cd754599e#gistcomment-3241210) (and other useful data) in Node with fs:

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const buff = Buffer.alloc(100);
const header = Buffer.from("mvhd");

async function main() {
 const file = await fs.open("video.mp4", "r");
 const { buffer } = await file.read(buff, 0, 100, 0);

 await file.close();

 const start = buffer.indexOf(header) + 17;
 const timeScale = buffer.readUInt32BE(start);
 const duration = buffer.readUInt32BE(start + 4);

 const audioLength = Math.floor((duration / timeScale) * 1000) / 1000;

 console.log(buffer, header, start, timeScale, duration, audioLength);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these three npm modules.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-video-duration (deprecated ?)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffprobe (deprecated)

The first one seems up to date. There is an example from the doc

```
const { getVideoDurationInSeconds } = require('get-video-duration')

// From a local path...
getVideoDurationInSeconds('video.mov').then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})

// From a URL...
getVideoDurationInSeconds('http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4').then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})

// From a readable stream...

const fs = require('fs')
const stream = fs.createReadStream('video.mov')

getVideoDurationInSeconds(stream).then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The content length of a media file has no simple relationship to the media length. However, you can use a media library like [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) to get accurate information about your media.

```
    //First save the buffer to a temporary file
    //...

    new ffmpeg('temp/temp-file-name.mp4', function (err, video) {
      if (!err) 
        console.log(video.metadata.duration.seconds)
    }
```